# Post array to PHP through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to post an array through ajax to php file on form submit.

```
<form action="echo.php" method="post">
<input name="qwerty[]" type="text">
<input name="qwerty[]" type="text">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Basically, I use this to post to php file:

```
function getlist(alt) {
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'markattlist.php',
    data:{today:alt},
    success: function(data){
    $('#helloflist').html(data);
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
```

Above is an example of what I'm trying to do. I've searched, but unable to find the solution to that. How can I post an array through ajax.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How can I post an array through ajax in the same way?

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize the form data using `data:$('#form').serialize()` function and can send it using ajax or you can use JSON data type to send an array.

```
var Data = $('#yorFormName').serializeArray();
var JSONData = JSON.stringify(convertToJSON(Data));

 $.ajax({
        url: your_url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSONData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {

            if (response.status == 'success') {
            // success logic
           } 
        },
        error: function () {
            var errMsg = "Unexpected Server Error! Please Try again later";


        }

    });
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bothering how to send what you need, I advise you to use jquery [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method:

```
function getlist(alt) {
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'markattlist.php',
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        $('#helloflist').html(data);
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
```

And check on server-side with

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: This looks good, but i've to insert it into mysql.  How can I then distinguish posted data on server ?

Comment: distinguish from what?

Comment: I'm posting multiple <input name="qwerty[]" type="text"> and multiple <input name="hello[]" type="text">

Comment: How will I know which one is qwerty[] and hello[] ?

Comment: I got what I needed.

Comment: What to do if I have multiple forms on my page? $("form").serialize() will get values from all forms

Comment: Add id  or class to form.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: JSON.stringify({d:c}),
```

Encode it as json and decode it on the server:

```
$data=json_decode($_POST["data"]);
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is d:c ?

Comment: {} is just an object. You could also put [] an array inside the stringify function

Comment: See afshans answer for a better example with jquery and ajax

Comment: u_mulder had a better approach.